# Does threadpool kill their threads that have been sleeping by thread.sleep for a long time (more than 5 minutes)?

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, threadpool

In my code, the main thread runs a task by TaskFactory.StartNew method at fixed intervals(1 second).

The runned task costs 5 seconds on average. But  the task costs 5*5 minutes if an SQL exception is raised.(If an SQL exception is raised, task execute (Thread.Sleep(300000) + Retry) * 5 and task exits normally.) The runned task blocks main thread because the task update a table that referenced by main thread.

As a matter of fact, this program hunged up. From the logs, the runned task updated a table and did not end. So main thread is blocked all the way. This hangging does not raised always, raised very rarely.(It occured just once when I had been running this program for three days.)

I think that the runned task raised SQLException and threadpool kills this thread when sleeping by Thread.Sleep(300000).(Because I read that threadpool often kills not used threads.)

Is my thought wrong? (Indeed, I can not find similar problems in internet.)

※From reading the source, I can not find out place where not to handle exceptions in the runned task.(It means that I don't think it's dropping in unhandled exceptions.)

Comment: "I think that the runned task raised SQLException and threadpool kills this thread when sleeping by". Do you have any type of logging at this point?

Comment: Thank you for replying.I did not. So It's just a guess.

Comment: *"I did not"*. Then you next step is obvious.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes, it is clear. But it needs a permission, To get a permission I need a hypothesis that could occur. So,I need a my thouht can be occured.

Comment: You don't need a hypothesis at all, and any process that says you do is fundamentally a broken process. Something clearly went wrong, that is not contested. The obvious thing to identify what is to look at the logging - in particular: exceptions. But you didn't have any. You want to find what went wrong: *add some logging*. Adding guesswork doesn't improve things.

Comment: I modified  at fixed intervals(1 minutes) to (1 seconds)

Comment: Thank you for replying. OK, It's right. I would add some logging somehow or other.

Comment: But this is purely a question, just out of curiosity, whether it is related to my problem or not, is it possible to have an event like the one in the title (i.e., ThreadPool kills a Thread that has been stopped for a long time by Thread.Sleep)?Or is it an impossible phenomenon to begin with?

Comment: To me,  if an exception (or anything for that matter ) on a one thread is blocking ANY other thread,  there really is a fundamental design issue within your application.  Threads should be independent

Comment: Thank you for replying.I have the same feeling. (So I've been told.) This program is full of strange things happening. It's not the program I wrote, though. I feel that maybe my problem has nothing to do with the question in the title. (I'm curious if such an event like title could happen, though.)

Comment: However, it is certainly strange that it would block for a long time when an exception is raised. I'll report back to see if it needs to be fixed. Thank you very much.